# How are champion displacement moves prioritized?

Tags: league-of-legends

If Blitzcrank grabs Amumu, who bandages an enemy, and Nautilus anchors one of them, would that pull them towards one another?

How will these moves affect jump/dash moves like Tristana's Rocket Jump, or Lee Sin's Dash, or Alistar's Headbutt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That answers the double grab question. Anything more than that idk. Doesn't Nautilus displace both champions a little like they meet halfway or something? That would make it a lot more complicated indeed.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on exactly what order the abilities hit. I think the general rule is that the last ability wins out, although champs might be moved around by the earlier abilities in the meantime. Note that many of these abilities also have mini-stuns built in, so you can't (for example) throw a bandage while blitz is grabbing you.